# back to previous fragment from other fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have main activity and 2 fragments on it, fragment1 call fragment2
When I am clicking the back button from the built in android buttons it call the onBackPressed function that I overrided in the main activity and exit me from the app.
I want that when I click back on the fragment 2 the onBackPressed of the main activity will not called and it will back me to fragment 1. 
The back button of the action bar works well (I think it mean that the backstack is ok).

I tried to do:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("Messages");
```

on the fragment 2

And tried to add

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

to the onBackPressed() of the main activity
It dosen't did nothing
Thank you

EDIT:

```
I am trying to do 
    public void onBackPressed() {
//      getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(null);
        if (fragment2 != null && fragment2.isVisible()) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return;
        }
```

and before any show

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();
        tr.show(Fragment2);
```

but got null on the findFragment(null)

EDIT:
I checked getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().mTail.fragment and saw that the value is the Fragment 1 that I want to be showed, but when I do getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); it dosen't nothing.

Comment: I think by default, when addBackStack, the Os will do the same behavior you expect without overide the onBackPressed.
Maybe you misimplement some where else, can you post more of you code?

Comment: @Minhtdh is right.Any error you are getting?

Comment: No don't have any error, and it's alot of code so it's problem but I edited the post with more info

Comment: Ok, I think it's because of getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit(); When you call this code, it's will add a backstack with no UI. So if you don't override onBackStack, you can go back to your 1st fragment after 2 back press.
What is "tr" variable?

Comment: I did not have onBackStack call, tr it is : final FragmentTransaction tr = getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction();

Comment: @LiorPozin Sorry that I miss typed, I mean method onBackPressed. Because the answer quite long, so I add new answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Override onBackPressed() in Main activity.

Check the currently displayed fragment, if fragment2 is displayed, then pop back stack.

example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment2 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
    if (fragment2 != null && fragment2.isVisible()) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before showing the fragment in the main activity I did getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit(); and after that did your solution and when I did getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(null) it's still show me null, I don't know why..

Comment: when you are adding/replacing the fragment itself, you have to give the tag name, beginTransaction().add(fragment2, "tag").commit(), then you will not get null.

Answer (score 0):

just use below way; in your Activity check this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SecondFragment");
            if (fragment instanceof SecondFragment) {
                // show first fragment
            }else{
               // finish();
            }
   }
```

i have used findFragmentByTag, you can also use findFragmentById

i agree with @Minhtdh comment but it only applicable if you replace one over other

Comment: Before showing the fragment in the main activity I did getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit(); and after that did your solution and when I did getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(null) it's still show me null, I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

Before calling fragment2.show() in the MainActivity, add the fragmnet transaction to backstack. There is no need to override onBackPressed().By default android implements the same functionality for you.

Comment: Before showing the fragment in the main activity I did getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit(); and after that did your solution and when I did getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(null) it's still show me null, I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

simple working code. 
to get back to 1st fargment.

```
yourviewvariable.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Before showing the fragment in the main activity I did getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit(); and after that did your solution and when I did getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(null) it's still show me null, I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I miss typed, I mean method onBackPressed.
But for your case, because you use FragmentTransition.show(), it will not add the fragment to backstack and popBackStack won't work. So I think you should try this:
1. don't called `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();` because it add an unnecessary backstack.
2. don't store the "tr" variable as global variable, and you also need call commit() to end the transaction: 
`Fragment2.setTag("fragment2");
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(Fragment2).commit();`
3. in onBackPressed():

```
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment2");
    if (fragment2 != null && fragment2.isVisible()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment2).commit();
        return;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I still got null on the     android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment2");